# How to host angular website in personal server with registered domain

Tags: node.js, iis, xampp, web-hosting, angular-fullstack

We have developed an angular website and we have both personal server and a registered domain extension. We were able to host through public ip using iis but when the domain name was used in throws NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID. It also redirects to https by default.

We also tried using xampp too. We don't want to use any cloud servers as our custom domain extension can't be used.

kindly help us to host the website.

Comment: Maybe you need a SSL cert? Try with Let's Encrypt

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned the error message: `ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID`.

This issue is related to your certificate. If you do not currently have a certificate, you can choose to create a self-signed certificate, or apply for a certificate from the Authority.

If you already have a certificate and still have this issue, you can check to see if it is expired and try renewing the certificate.